# How to change the shape of colorbar in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to have such an arrow-shaped colorbar in Matlab?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb7rS.jpg)

Comment: You could try this one: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52515-cbarrow-pointy-ends-for-colorbars

Comment: I doubt it is possible but there are undocumented options you may be able to use. Here (https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/415867-add-units-to-colorbar-ticklabels-format) you have a link for an UNDOCUMENTED tool to explore hidden options

Comment: Not in a standard way no.